# How to check if a reference is null or not

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have a function that creates an `order`.
I need to know the `Ogrn` field is null or not. How should I do it?

Func:

```
func CreateOrder(c *gin.Context) {
    var order models.Order
    var form models.Form
    if &form.Ogrn == nil {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        ...})
}
```

Struct:

```
type Form struct {
    gorm.Model
    ...
    Ogrn string `json:"ogrn"`
    ...
}
```

Comment: Agreed, we can't answer this question without you showing the type of `form.Ogrn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `Ogrn` property on your `Form` struct is a `string`, you can't check to see if it's `nil`.

You can either check to see if it's empty as that is the `string` types default value in Go. Or, you can change your struct so `Ogrn` is a pointer to a string, `*string`. You can then check to see if it's `nil`.

```golang
type Form struct {
    ...
    Ogrn *string
}

func CreateOrder(c *gin.Context) {
    var form models.Form

    if form.Ogrn == nil {
        // Do something when nil.
    }
    ...
}
```